Why can't I calculate the closest intersection point of a ray and a signed distance field directly?
Signed distance fields (SDFs) are functions in computer graphics, that implicitly define the surface of a geometric primitive (e.g. spheres, boxes, pyramids, etc.) by returning the distance to the closest point on its surface, given a query point. More precisely, given a point $p$ the surface of a shape is defined as:
$SDF(p)=0$
A ray is defined by an origin $r_o$ and a direction $r_d$. Any point $p$ on this ray satisfies $p=r_o+t*r_d$, where $t$ is some distance along the ray.
SDFs are traditionally evaluated using a rendering approach called ray marching, where steps are taken along a ray to iteratively find a point on the SDF's surface. There obviously has to be a reason for this approach, otherwise a direct intersection with the ray would be the norm.
However, I am not good enough at maths to understand why. Why can't I plug the definition of "points on a ray" into the definition of a SDF and resolve the intersection point that way?
Shouldn't something akin to this be possible somehow?
$SDF(r_o+t*r_d)=0$
I am missing something here, but I don't know what. The definitions are generally too "codified" for me to apply any mathematical rules by myself - In particular I don't know how to represent shader code functions like "max" and "min" in a mathematical equation.
EDIT 1:
I've put some more work into it and have extracted the main issue that plagues this problem. The approach itself turns out to be logically sound, in fact, the ray intersection with the much simpler shape of a sphere could be considered a derivation from the SDF:
https://facultyweb.cs.wwu.edu/~wehrwes/courses/csci480_21w/lectures/L07/L07_notes.pdf
Of course, this could also just be a coincidence since the definition of a sphere's surface is simple to begin with.
The main issue with this ray-intersection derivation is the definition of the rounded box SDF itself. More precisely the fact that the absolute value of the query point is used. When inserting the definition of the ray into an absolute value (|x|) clause, internal variables can not be solved for as far as I know. Unfortunately it also doesn't seem possible to define a different SDF for a box without using the absolute value of the query point one way or another.
But I am no math-prodigy, so if there is a solution to this problem, please enlighten me!

It all depends on the SDF. If it is an equation up to 4th degree, then you could indeed solve it directly. If it is something determined by multiple equations you could solve each one individually and then choose the best $t$. But there may be shapes described by something different and you may not be able to solve it directly

It seems that the SDF ray marching is used in fact because you may have very complicated SDFs (think about multiple objects, maybe partly overlapping), and in this case it is indeed faster to find the best intersection by an approximation method rather than solving all the equations

The closet point would be $$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} SDF(\boldsymbol{r}_o+t,\boldsymbol{e})=0 $$

@Exodd I‘ve been trying to make it work over the past days and I think the problem is, that SDFs return the closest distance to the surface, but we need the distance to a point along the ray. These are two different types of distances, which is why I can‘t really substitute the SDF query point parameter with the ray formula… at least that‘s what I‘ve figured out for rounded boxes.

@JohnAlexiou I‘m not super adept in mathematical notation unfortunately, so excuse the question: the first part of your equation is the derivative isn‘t it?  Why would you place it there / why do you think it‘s needed?

@JohnAlexiou or more importantly, what‘s $e$?

@Chribit - $\boldsymbol{e}$ is the ray direction vector. The derivative is used to find the closest point on the ray to the object. The distance remains approximately the same near the closest point as $t$ varies.

@JohnAlexiou I finally got around to your recommendation and unfortunately that won't work. The derivative of the SDF can be used to get accurate normals at any given surface point, but not to get the intersection point along a ray. The calculation of the derivative removes any constants within the equation, which is the case for the radius of a rounded box for example since it's subtracted from the "sharp" box SDF. Since the radius then isn't in the equation any more, the intersection point never is on the SDF surface. Or do you have any Idea how this issue could be mitigated?
